# Complex numbers (operation)

Tags: complex-analysis

> Which of the following is obtained when computing $2^{-50}\left(1 + \mathbf i\right)^{101} + 1 + 1$?
>
> $a)\,\,0$
>
> $b)\,\,1 + \mathbf i$
>
> $c)\,\,1 - \mathbf i$
>
> $d)\,\,1 + 2\mathbf i$

Comment: What do you think?

Comment: @ajax2112 the correct answer is 0 but i don't know how to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
& 2^{-50}(1+i)^{101}+1+1 \\
=& 2^{-50} \times(\sqrt{2})^{101} \times \operatorname{cis}\left(\frac{101 \pi}{4}\right)+2 \\
=& 2^{-50} \times 2^{50.5} \times \operatorname{cis}\left(\frac{5 \pi}{4}\right)+2 \\
=& \sqrt{2} \times \operatorname{cis} \left(\frac{-3 \pi}{4}\right)+2 \\
=& \sqrt{2} \cos \left(\frac{-3 \pi}{4}\right)+i \sqrt{2} \sin \left(\frac{-3 \pi}{4}\right)+2 \\
=&-1-i+2 \\
=& 1-i
\end{aligned}\end{equation}

Comment: Thank you so much